# ValueError in CVXPY minization function (Minimum Variance Optimization)

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, minimization, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I'm a bit of a beginner and in the process of moving an algorithm that works with minimum variance optimization from **`scipy.minimize.optimize`** (which didn't perform properly) to **`CVXPY`**.

***`R`*** are the expected returns, ***`C`*** the coveriances and ***`rf`*** the risk-free rate. ***`w`*** are the optimal weights and ***`r`*** various means along the Efficient Frontier for which the weights are calculated.

When I run the code below I get:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I believe var is at fault here, but I don't know how else to structure it. Insight much appreciated. On top of that, **the rest of the code could have additional errors so if you spot any please do point them out!**

```
def solve_frontier(R, C, rf, context):
        frontier_mean, frontier_var, frontier_weights = [], [], []
        n = len(R)
        w = cvx.Variable(n)
        r = cvx.Parameter(sign='positive')
        mean_1 = sum(R*w)  
        var = dot(dot(w, C), w)
        penalty = (1/100)*abs(mean_1-r)

        prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(var + penalty),
                       [sum(w)-context.allowableMargin == 0])

        r_vals = linspace(max(min(R), rf), max(R), num=20)
        for i in range(20):
            r.value = r_vals[i]
            prob.solve()
            frontier_mean.append(r)
            frontier_var.append(compute_var(prob.value, C))
            frontier_weights.append(prob.value) 
            print "status:", prob.status
        return array(frontier_mean), array(frontier_var), frontier_weights
```

Comment: The error should tell you exactly the line where the problem occurs. Please get that information. Also if you read up on [minimum complete verifiable questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your question, it will probably get a better response in addition to being more helpful for future users.

Comment: I'm using an ipython notebook and it doesn't actually say which line's problematic. I'll try and make it mcv.

Comment: This part looks suspicious to me `[sum(w)-context.allowableMargin == 0]`. Do you really intend to pass a single boolean in a list as an argument? If not what do you intend? Also, are you saying that the code above prints the value error that you mentioned? If so, that `Problem` class is strange for hiding an unhandled error and you will want to focus on what is going on in that class.

Comment: allowableMargin is set to either 1 or more depending on arbitrary conditions; the constraint implicitly ensures the weights sum to 1 for non-leveraged trading or higher if leverage is in play. If I debug manually I can see the error thrown at the definition of "var"; could this be an NaN problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in `frontier_mean.append(r)`, which should have been `frontier_mean.append(r.value)`.